# d3.js Sankey Link Transition not transitioning in-place (jsbin provided)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sankey-diagram

Here is my jsbin: https://jsbin.com/fepakitayi/edit?html,output

Press the "transition" button to transition graph.

Everything is working fine (text is transitioning, titles are transitioning, nodes are transitioning) and the links are transitioning but for some reason they scatter about and THEN change sizes; that is, they disconnect from the two nodes they are attached to ad reconnect to two different nodes. Is there a way to make the links transition to the new size in-place? For example, I'd like for them to transition WITH the nodes and only shift if their respective node shifts.

BTW, jsbin didn't have an option to add the d3.sankey library so I had to put that in with my js so it's a bit cluttered, but my code is at the bottom of the javascript section.

Relevant code:

After the `on('click'` event, I update the `graph.links` and then transition to the new `graph.links` with new stroke-width.

```
link
  // svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
      .transition()
      .duration(1000) 
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", path)
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.max(1, d.dy); })
```

I've searched google for d3.sankey transitions but didn't find much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got data-binding troubles with your `graph.links` variable.  Since you don't specify a [key function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data), when you re-bind your data the links don't stay associated to the same nodes they belonged to before.  An easy fix is:

```
link
    .data(graph.links, function(d) {
      return d.source.name + d.target.name; //<-- create a key that keeps a link associated with it's nodes
    })
    .transition()
    .duration(1000) 
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", path)
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.max(1, d.dy); });
```

---

Full working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/lu4nW2RFwZBkW0DRBacn?p=preview).

Comment: This is perfect, Mark. Thank you. I knew there was something I just wasn't understanding about it, but this makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to update the content of d3 sankey chart on mouse click. The new nodes and links are not getting updated. Below is the code and any inputs to fix it would be great.

The new nodes and links remains the same, if its updated with new nodes and links for the new set of data.

```js
d3.sankey = function() {
  var sankey = {},
    nodeWidth = 24,
    nodePadding = 8,
    size = [1, 1],
    nodes = [],
    links = [];
  sankey.nodeWidth = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return nodeWidth;
    nodeWidth = +_;
    return sankey;
  };
  sankey.nodePadding = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return nodePadding;
    nodePadding = +_;
    return sankey;
  };
  sankey.nodes = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return nodes;
    nodes = _;
    return sankey;
  };
  sankey.links = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return links;
    links = _;
    return sankey;
  };
  sankey.size = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return size;
    size = _;
    return sankey;
  };
  sankey.layout = function(iterations) {
    computeNodeLinks();
    computeNodeValues();
    computeNodeBreadths();
    computeNodeDepths(iterations);
    computeLinkDepths();
    return sankey;
  };
  sankey.relayout = function() {
    computeLinkDepths();
    return sankey;
  };
  sankey.link = function() {
    var curvature = .5;

    function link(d) {
      var x0 = d.source.x + d.source.dx,
        x1 = d.target.x,
        xi = d3.interpolateNumber(x0, x1),
        x2 = xi(curvature),
        x3 = xi(1 - curvature),
        y0 = d.source.y + d.sy + d.dy / 2,
        y1 = d.target.y + d.ty + d.dy / 2;
      return "M" + x0 + "," + y0 + "C" + x2 + "," + y0 + " " + x3 + "," + y1 + " " + x1 + "," + y1;
    }
    link.curvature = function(_) {
      if (!arguments.length) return curvature;
      curvature = +_;
      return link;
    };
    return link;
  };
  // Populate the sourceLinks and targetLinks for each node.
  // Also, if the source and target are not objects, assume they are indices.
  function computeNodeLinks() {
    nodes.forEach(function(node) {
      node.sourceLinks = [];
      node.targetLinks = [];
    });
    links.forEach(function(link) {
      var source = link.source,
        target = link.target;
      if (typeof source === "number") source = link.source = nodes[link.source];
      if (typeof target === "number") target = link.target = nodes[link.target];
      source.sourceLinks.push(link);
      target.targetLinks.push(link);
    });
  }
  // Compute the value (size) of each node by summing the associated links.
  function computeNodeValues() {
    nodes.forEach(function(node) {
      node.value = Math.max(
        d3.sum(node.sourceLinks, value),
        d3.sum(node.targetLinks, value)
      );
    });
  }
  // Iteratively assign the breadth (x-position) for each node.
  // Nodes are assigned the maximum breadth of incoming neighbors plus one;
  // nodes with no incoming links are assigned breadth zero, while
  // nodes with no outgoing links are assigned the maximum breadth.
  function computeNodeBreadths() {
    var remainingNodes = nodes,
      nextNodes,
      x = 0;
    while (remainingNodes.length) {
      nextNodes = [];
      remainingNodes.forEach(function(node) {
        node.x = x;
        node.dx = nodeWidth;
        node.sourceLinks.forEach(function(link) {
          if (nextNodes.indexOf(link.target) < 0) {
            nextNodes.push(link.target);
          }
        });
      });
      remainingNodes = nextNodes;
      ++x;
    }
    //
    moveSinksRight(x);
    scaleNodeBreadths((size[0] - nodeWidth) / (x - 1));
  }

  function moveSourcesRight() {
    nodes.forEach(function(node) {
      if (!node.targetLinks.length) {
        node.x = d3.min(node.sourceLinks, function(d) {
          return d.target.x;
        }) - 1;
      }
    });
  }

  function moveSinksRight(x) {
    nodes.forEach(function(node) {
      if (!node.sourceLinks.length) {
        node.x = x - 1;
      }
    });
  }

  function scaleNodeBreadths(kx) {
    nodes.forEach(function(node) {
      node.x *= kx;
    });
  }

  function computeNodeDepths(iterations) {
    var nodesByBreadth = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .sortKeys(d3.ascending)
      .entries(nodes)
      .map(function(d) {
        return d.values;
      });
    //
    initializeNodeDepth();
    resolveCollisions();
    for (var alpha = 1; iterations > 0; --iterations) {
      relaxRightToLeft(alpha *= .99);
      resolveCollisions();
      relaxLeftToRight(alpha);
      resolveCollisions();
    }

    function initializeNodeDepth() {
      var ky = d3.min(nodesByBreadth, function(nodes) {
        return (size[1] - (nodes.length - 1) * nodePadding) / d3.sum(nodes, value);
      });
      nodesByBreadth.forEach(function(nodes) {
        nodes.forEach(function(node, i) {
          node.y = i;
          node.dy = node.value * ky;
        });
      });
      links.forEach(function(link) {
        link.dy = link.value * ky;
      });
    }

    function relaxLeftToRight(alpha) {
      nodesByBreadth.forEach(function(nodes, breadth) {
        nodes.forEach(function(node) {
          if (node.targetLinks.length) {
            var y = d3.sum(node.targetLinks, weightedSource) / d3.sum(node.targetLinks, value);
            node.y += (y - center(node)) * alpha;
          }
        });
      });

      function weightedSource(link) {
        return center(link.source) * link.value;
      }
    }

    function relaxRightToLeft(alpha) {
      nodesByBreadth.slice().reverse().forEach(function(nodes) {
        nodes.forEach(function(node) {
          if (node.sourceLinks.length) {
            var y = d3.sum(node.sourceLinks, weightedTarget) / d3.sum(node.sourceLinks, value);
            node.y += (y - center(node)) * alpha;
          }
        });
      });

      function weightedTarget(link) {
        return center(link.target) * link.value;
      }
    }

    function resolveCollisions() {
      nodesByBreadth.forEach(function(nodes) {
        var node,
          dy,
          y0 = 0,
          n = nodes.length,
          i;
        // Push any overlapping nodes down.
        nodes.sort(ascendingDepth);
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
          node = nodes[i];
          dy = y0 - node.y;
          if (dy > 0) node.y += dy;
          y0 = node.y + node.dy + nodePadding;
        }
        // If the bottommost node goes outside the bounds, push it back up.
        dy = y0 - nodePadding - size[1];
        if (dy > 0) {
          y0 = node.y -= dy;
          // Push any overlapping nodes back up.
          for (i = n - 2; i >= 0; --i) {
            node = nodes[i];
            dy = node.y + node.dy + nodePadding - y0;
            if (dy > 0) node.y -= dy;
            y0 = node.y;
          }
        }
      });
    }

    function ascendingDepth(a, b) {
      return a.y - b.y;
    }
  }

  function computeLinkDepths() {
    nodes.forEach(function(node) {
      node.sourceLinks.sort(ascendingTargetDepth);
      node.targetLinks.sort(ascendingSourceDepth);
    });
    nodes.forEach(function(node) {
      var sy = 0,
        ty = 0;
      node.sourceLinks.forEach(function(link) {
        link.sy = sy;
        sy += link.dy;
      });
      node.targetLinks.forEach(function(link) {
        link.ty = ty;
        ty += link.dy;
      });
    });

    function ascendingSourceDepth(a, b) {
      return a.source.y - b.source.y;
    }

    function ascendingTargetDepth(a, b) {
      return a.target.y - b.target.y;
    }
  }

  function center(node) {
    return node.y + node.dy / 2;
  }

  function value(link) {
    return link.value;
  }
  return sankey;
};



var source = [{
  "source": "L1",
  "sourceNpi": "1477640589",
  "target": "L2",
  "targetNpi": "1932170750",
  "value": 29
}, {
  "source": "L2",
  "sourceNpi": "1386731404",
  "target": "L3",
  "targetNpi": "1932170750",
  "value": 22
}];

var source1 = [{
    "source": "L1",
    "sourceNpi": "1477640589",
    "target": "L2",
    "targetNpi": "1932170750",
    "value": 2
  }, {
    "source": "L2",
    "sourceNpi": "1386731404",
    "target": "L3",
    "targetNpi": "1932170750",
    "value": 15
  },
  {
    "source": "L2",
    "sourceNpi": "1386731404",
    "target": "L4",
    "targetNpi": "1932170750",
    "value": 15
  }
];

run();

function run() {

  var units = "";

  var margin = {
      top: 10,
      right: 10,
      bottom: 10,
      left: 10
    },
    width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var formatNumber = d3.format(",.0f"), // zero decimal places
    format = function(d) {
      return formatNumber(d) + " " + units;
    },
    color = d3.scale.category20();

  //Clear the existing SVG element to overwrite it
  d3.select('svg').remove();

  // append the svg canvas to the page
  var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  // Set the sankey diagram properties
  var sankey = d3.sankey()
    .nodeWidth(36)
    .nodePadding(40)
    .size([width, height]);

  var path = sankey.link();

  var data = source;

  graph = {
    "nodes": [],
    "links": []
  };


  data.forEach(function(d) {
    graph.nodes.push({
      "name": d.source
    });
    graph.nodes.push({
      "name": d.target
    });
    graph.links.push({
      "source": d.source,
      "target": d.target,
      "value": +d.value
    });
  });

  // return only the distinct / unique nodes
  graph.nodes = d3.keys(d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .map(graph.nodes));

  // loop through each link replacing the text with its index from node
  graph.links.forEach(function(d, i) {
    graph.links[i].source = graph.nodes.indexOf(graph.links[i].source);
    graph.links[i].target = graph.nodes.indexOf(graph.links[i].target);
  });

  //now loop through each nodes to make nodes an array of objects
  // rather than an array of strings
  graph.nodes.forEach(function(d, i) {
    graph.nodes[i] = {
      "name": d
    };
  });

  sankey
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .links(graph.links)
    .layout(32);

  // add in the links
  var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link")
    .data(graph.links, function(d) {
      return d.source.name + d.target.name;
    })
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", path)
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) {
      return Math.max(1, d.dy);
    })
    .sort(function(a, b) {
      return b.dy - a.dy;
    });

  // add the link titles
  link.append("title")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.source.name + " → " +
        d.target.name + "\n" + format(d.value);
    });

  // add in the nodes
  var node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    })
    .call(d3.behavior.drag()
      .origin(function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .on("dragstart", function() {
        this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
      })
      .on("drag", dragmove));

  // add the rectangles for the nodes
  node.append("rect")
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return d.dy;
    })
    .attr("width", sankey.nodeWidth())
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d.color = color(d.name.replace(/ .*/, ""));
    })
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
      return d3.rgb(d.color).darker(2);
    })
    .append("title")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name + "\n" + format(d.value);
    });

  // add in the title for the nodes
  node.append("text")
    .attr("x", -6)
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return d.dy / 2;
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("transform", null)
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .filter(function(d) {
      return d.x < width / 2;
    })
    .attr("x", 6 + sankey.nodeWidth())
    .attr("text-anchor", "start");

  // the function for moving the nodes
  function dragmove(d) {
    d3.select(this).attr("transform",
      "translate(" + d.x + "," + (
        d.y = Math.max(0, Math.min(height - d.dy, d3.event.y))
      ) + ")");
    sankey.relayout();
    link.attr("d", path);
  }

  d3.select("#here")
    .on("click", function() {

      sankey.relayout(3);

      data = source1;
      graph = {
        "nodes": [],
        "links": []
      };

      data.forEach(function(d) {
        graph.nodes.push({
          name: d.source
        });
        graph.nodes.push({
          name: d.target
        });

        graph.links.push({
          source: d.source,
          target: d.target,
          value: d.value
        });
      });

      console.log(" nodes " + graph.nodes);
      // return only the distinct / unique nodes
      graph.nodes = d3.keys(d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) {
          return d.name;
        })
        .map(graph.nodes));



      // loop through each link replacing the text with its index from node
      graph.links.forEach(function(d, i) {
        console.log(graph.nodes.indexOf(graph.links[i].source) + "  " + graph.nodes.indexOf(graph.links[i].target));
        graph.links[i].source = graph.nodes.indexOf(graph.links[i].source);
        graph.links[i].target = graph.nodes.indexOf(graph.links[i].target);
      });

      graph.nodes.forEach(function(d, i) {
        console.log("for each" + d + i);
        graph.nodes[i] = {
          "name": d
        };
      });

      // console.log(" nodes "+ graph.nodes[3].name);
      //console.log(" nodes "+ graph.nodes[4].name);

      sankey
        .nodes(graph.nodes)
        .links(graph.links)
        .layout(32);


      interpolate = null;

      console.log("checked nodes" + graph.nodes);
      //node.data().slice();
      node.data(graph.nodes, function(d) {
          console.log("inside node " + d.name);
          return d.name;
        })
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          console.log("translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")" + d.name)
          return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });


      link
        .data(graph.links, function(d) {
          console.log("links " + d.source.name + d.target.name);
          return d.source.name + d.target.name;
        })
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", path)
        .style("stroke-width", function(d) {
          return Math.max(1, d.dy);
        });



      svg.selectAll(".link>title")
        .data(graph.links)
        .transition()
        .text(function(d) {
          console.log(" links " + d.source.name + d.target.name);
          return d.source.name + " → " +
            d.target.name + "\n" + format(d.value);
        });

      svg.selectAll("rect").data(graph.nodes)
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("height", function(d) {
          return d.dy;
        });


      svg.selectAll(".node>rect>title")
        .data(graph.nodes)
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.name + "\n" + format(d.value);
        });

      svg.selectAll("text")
        .data(graph.nodes)
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("x", -6)
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return d.dy / 2;
        })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("transform", null)
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.name;
        })
        .filter(function(d) {
          return d.x < width / 2;
        })
        .attr("x", 6 + sankey.nodeWidth())
        .attr("text-anchor", "start");

      node.exit().remove();
      link.exit().remove();

    })


  // })
  ;
}
```

```css
.node rect {
  cursor: move;
  fill-opacity: .9;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.node text {
  pointer-events: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-opacity: .2;
}

.link:hover {
  stroke-opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.js"></script>

<button id="here" class="btn btn-default">transition</button>

<p id="chart"></p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1onlbirt/L29u04pf/6/